# Get JSON with jQuery and pass to php and back?

Tags: php, jquery, json, twitter

I want to get a Twitter search with jQuery and pass it to a php script for formatting.  I'm new to jQuery, so would love if someone could tell me if this hopelessly off?

This is my jQuery, which is supposed to call up Twitter, get the json, and then pass the json to php.

```
//jquery
$(document).ready(function() {
 var twUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter&rpp=5&callback=?";

     $.jsonp({
        url: twUrl,
        data: {},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        callbackParameter: "callback",
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data){
            $.post("search_back.php", {json_data: data},
                function(data) { $("#search_word").html() });
         }});            
});
```

and the php is supposed to pick it up, format it (not included, but I know how to do that part), and pass it back into the #search_word.

```
//search_back.php
$output = json_decode($_POST["data"], true);

foreach ($output as $tweet){
   echo $tweet;
}
```

Is this close? 
Really appreciate some help!

Comment: It is, that should work. You can var_dump($output) if you want to know about the structure

Comment: Thanks Nicolas! But, wouldn't you know it: it doesn't do anything! So there must be something wrong! Is it correct to use $.jsonp (and not $.ajax or getJson?)  Or am i passing the right vars with json_data and data? Thanks again!

Comment: jsonP is right, you cannot use ajax to do a crosssite call. You should check if data in $.jsonp actually has something in. use console.log(data); (if you use firebug) to check what there's in it

Comment: Yeah, console.log(data) is NULL. I wonder why?

Comment: on the php side, i see you were able to decode the json data.  before you send it back to the front-end, have you tried json_encode() for the tweet value and then echo the new variable?  so `foreach($output as $tweet){ $storedTweet = json_encode($tweet); echo $storedTweet;}`.  just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, excited now :)  Got it to work, just posting for reference:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var twUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=twitter&rpp=5&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(twUrl, 
        function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
            $.post("search_back.php", {json_data: data}, function(data) { 
                console.log(data);
                console.log("ok");
                $("#search_word").html(data) });

        }
    )});


</script>
```

and

```
<?php
$output = $_POST["json_data"];
foreach ($output[results] as $tweet){
    echo $tweet[from_user] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Seems what goes to php is already json_decoded,true?  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You should be sending a Json string, and using json_decode on php side, does the php script work for ya?

Comment: hmm, some data gets through, but there are definitively irregularities.. :) It's listed as Object in firebug, which is a bad sign, I guess. From what I understand I'm getting a json from twitter, and I should json_decode($output,true) in my php? I'll check it now.

Comment: could use your php to get the data from twitter and make your call to your own server...only one ajax call that way

Comment: yeah, what @charlietfl says is right. You could use curl or file_get_contents to get the json with PHP, then parse it and return it to your ajax call. It's a lot cleaner I think. Your problem is that getJson is automatically converting the string that comes from twitter into an object, you dont need that.

Comment: the reason i can't do that is because of rate limits. i'm making an app that will (hopefully) have a few thousand users, so the search requests (which are ip-rated only) will be rate-limited on my server. thus client-side is only solution, and it's now implemented thanks to you guys! =)

Comment: @Nicolas: but im interested in your comment about getJson returning object - is there any way to clean that up? why would it convert it into an object if it's called getJSON? anyway, that object - is it actually an associative array? or just a stdObject? it actually seems to work pretty well (save a few \" here and there... any idea how to clean that up as well?)  feel there must be a clean-up line to be added somewhere...